# Get Another User's Information by Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello I am new at facebook graph API 
when I used url like this 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me?fields=id,website,about,first_name,last_name,gender,birthday,education,age_range,email,%20television,movies,hometown,context,devices,favorite_teams,work&access_token=EAAM...

I can get website, first name , gender etc of me

but when I try to get another user's information from this url

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/{user id}?fields=id,website,about,first_name,last_name,gender,birthday,education,age_range,email,%20television,movies,hometown,context,devices,favorite_teams,work&access_token=EAAM...

I can get null values expect first_name, last_name and id

How can I correct the mistake? 
Note : the other user allows to show this info. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you grand some permissions with your app? Who is the owner of the access_token in your second request?

Comment: I gave all the permissions in [link](http://i.imgur.com/UnHyVHz.jpg) here . The owner is same with the first one.

Comment: Access_token must be owned by the other user you want to see the details.

Comment: I want to develop a facebook monitoring application and the user can be see  information (gender, hometown,  email ..)  of another users who liked his posts, pictures etc. How can do it?

Comment: You can’t. Those other users would have to login to your app and grant it permission to access that kind of data first.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Sure. How can softwares like hootsuite do this operations?

Comment: They ask people to login through FB to grant the permission to access that kind of data first.

Comment: Thanks for your help.